# File already exists. error occured when i am trying to make my .apk signed in android

Tags: android, apk, keystore, signed

I am trying to create the signed .apk by following these steps

Step : 1 Right Click Project->Export Application->Select you Project->Next->Select new Keystore -> Complete all rest Steps

Step : 2 Note down your Alias name and Password given.

Step : 3 Now if you Complete all process of Filling Details you will get one .apk file and keystore file in you stored location.

Step : 4 Now Again Right Click Project->Export Application->Select you Project->Next->Use Existing Keystore -> Give location and password->Next

Step : 5 Now you alias name will comes in your Drop Down->Select it -> Enter Password -> Next

Step : 6 It will ask for location to store your final .apk file.

Step : 7 Select your location and store.

Step : 8 Now this Final .apk file is Your Signed Application.

But at the Step no 1 when i try to create the new keystore an error occurred   `File already exists.`   below is the screen shot of that. I am not understand this thing and put a lot of effort but never get out of it. Any help is appreciated

[image: File already exist]

Comment: Check whether already an `.apk` in that location - `E:\application\Geography.apk`

Comment: @Naresh there is .apk use keystore file

Comment: @SamirMangroliya how can i used the Keystore file and create it

Comment: @SpK yes there is an apk but i following the above steps and doing this thing 1st time so not much aware about the things. i have done this earlier for another app and that .apk is generated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore

Comment: Try to Use other location. Like in (E:\New_Folder\) means, create a new folder to some locations. And, use that location.

Comment: @SpK  but in that location what i have to get an .apk or some key and how that key is generated. i am totally confused this time

Comment: [Try this one](http://pastie.org/4067883)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to create a keystore as an apk, but that is incorrect.
The keystore is not an app or something, just name it something like `key`, then enter your password and confirm the password.

In a later screen you will be asked where to export your .apk file.

Comment: In location column what i will give the key or the .apk ?

Comment: Something like e:\application\key

Comment: what is key here and how can i get it. i read some keytool cmd's but didn't get much out of it

Comment: `key` is just an extensionless file which holds data regarding the creation of your apk. If you fill in the screen of your screenshot like I said, the key file will be created. You don't need keytool for this.

Comment: one key file and .apk is generated. Is that the signed one