# Android export : how to create .keystore file?

Tags: android, eclipse, export, keystore

I'm trying to export my Android application from Eclipse, and so I'm stuck at the 2nd step where I need to create a new keystore. What should I put in the location field ?

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: This is the answer: [How to sign an android apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4853025/735675)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sign an android apk file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853011/how-to-sign-an-android-apk-file)

Comment: Just follow the link below and you will be able to create keystore of you app. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/publish-to-android-market/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a keystore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore)

Comment: here is nice and Easy tutorial. check it. [How to create Keystore file](http://androidhelpblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-create-key-store-file.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I'm stuck at the 2nd step where I need to create a new keystore. What
>   should I put in the location field ?

That location field is the location where you want to keep new keystore file and give name to keystore file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have this official guide to achieve that,

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal by typing cmd in seach and run command prompt.

In terminal write `cd  %JAVA_HOME%\bin` it will take you to java bin directory.

Here you paste following line:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore e:\store-key.keystore -alias store-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

It prompt you for your name and other things just give these things to terminal and password when it ask and your key file will be generated in E drive with the name of 
**store-key.keystore**