# debug.Keystore format file i try to open it using notepad?

Tags: android

I am developing gps base app. For that i need the md5 so i have tried to open the file debug.keystore using notepad,so file format is change to notepad, now i have got the google-apiKey using key-tool menu (install plug-in keytool ), but problem is that when run my app it give me the following error

Error generating final archive: `java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format         Unknown  Android Packaging Problem`

I am not even sure where to begin to look. I cannot launch the application. Can someone give me an idea on what area I can look into?

A
I am solve this problem

Delete your debug certificate under ~/.android/debug.keystore on Linux and Mac OS X; the directory is something like %USERPROFILE%/.androidon Windows.

The Eclipse plug-in should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.
Your debug keystore was created automatically

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3997748/1689695

Comment: Why you open debug.keystore? Do not do it and look at TanjaV's link.

Comment: I am solve this problem                                             Delete your debug certificate under ~/.android/debug.keystore on Linux and Mac OS X; the directory is something like %USERPROFILE%/.androidon Windows.The Eclipse plug-in should then generate a new certificate when you next try to build a debug package. You may need to clean and then build to generate the certificate.
Your debug keystore was created automatically