# Generate Signed APK in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, apk

There are a few questions related to my question in Stackoverflow, such as:

[How do I export a project in the Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio)

[How to create a release signed apk file using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

They're good. But Still make me confused. When I selected Build->Generate signed APK in Android Studio, I got this warning message:

[image]

What does this mean? Does it mean I have to use gradle command line by config the build.gradle? Then what is the wizard for? If I just ignore the warning by click ok and follow the wizard to generate the apk file, I'll get error message saying the apk is in debug mode when I upload the apk to Google Play.

If I follow the instruction to setup the build.gradle like this:

```
 signingConfigs {

        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("../key/test.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "key"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

And everything is file when I run ./gradlew assembleRelease in terminal.

In summary, I'm confused at:

1. What is the purpose of "Generate signed APK" wizard if I have to setup the build.gradle
2. How to build my application in release mode when I run "Generate signed APK"

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: I got another issue. It's no problem to build it in terminal by using ./gradlew assembleRelease. And it's also no problem to Generate signed apk and install the apk into my device. But I got a "Installation failed since the APK was either not signed, or signed incorrectly." when I'm trying to run the app in my device.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In left bottom corner of Android Studio, select the Build Variances, then you can change the build mode to "release". When building in release mode, I think the "Generate Signed APK" wizard works. So just ignore the build.gradle configuration!