# How do i create a key store file in android studio?

Tags: java, android

How do i create a key store file in android studio? Its my first time publishing an app for android studio and I dont know what a key store file is and dont know how to use it. How do i make one for android studio instead of eclipse because when i search on google I only get results for making one for eclipse unless its exactly the same with android studio?

When i tried to make a key store and entered a random file for the key store path i got the error:
`keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Keystore file exists, but is empty: C:\Users\king__000\Documents\KeyStore`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keystore is a binary file which can be used to sign an application that you have developed. It is private key that you are issuing with the application. Android uses this certificate to identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio?answertab=votes#tab-top) link explains how to export an android app with Android studio.

navigate to your location and delete the empty keyfile and then create the new key file. Normally it fails if there is an existing file.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is this:

- Change your account type (on your PC or laptop) to Administrator.
- Then copy the file's URL (that you want to save the KeyStore to).
- Fill in your name, organization (if you have one), country code,
  passwords, etc.
- Click the OK button.
- Done.