Use Android Studio to install an APK file on my Android
Is there a way to push an APK to my Moto G Power using Android Studio???? Do I need to install anything other than android Studio? Not very accustomed to android Studio also. I'm using a moto g power (2022). I'm using the studio on debian Linux also if theirs any difference would like to state that.

Do you have the source code of the app? Or only the APK? The process to install the app would vary depending on what you are trying to do.

You can see if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676544/15031004

You don't need Android Studio adb from Android SDK is enough. using adb you can execute adb install <apkfilename> to install an app via USB. There are also third packages available named "adb minimal" that just contain adb without the necessity to download Android SDK.
