# I got an error when I upload the APK file

Tags: android, eclipse, upload, zipalign

I finished an application and I wanted to upload it thro google, I had this error

```
You uploaded an APK that is not zipaligned. You will need to run a zip align tool on your APK and upload it again.
```

I used zipalign and it told me "Verification succeeded" but when I upload it again, it gave me the same problem, any idea?

Comment: you must export it first

Comment: I did the export in it (finally :)) but at the end, it gave me this msg "keytool error:java.io.IOException: Incorrect AVA format"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio refer this