# Access is denied on Classes.dex in hello world android app

Tags: android

I am new to android. Using android studio when i try to run "Hello world", I get below error.Can anyone kindly help on this?

java.io.FileNotFoundException: .....\MyFirstApp\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug \classes.dex (Access is denied)

Provided classes.dex is available in the expected path.

Comment: Can you show your code, AndroidManifest, etc..?

Comment: I am pretty sure the directory "debug \classes" does not exists. I think the whitespace is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The build path it not exist, so you can change it
1. Open Project structure (F4 on one of the modules in the project explorer)
2. Click on Project tab on the left
3. Define "Project compiler output:" as YOUR_PROJECT_PATH\out (or any folder you want)
*update for new android studio" You can use menu RUN -> Edit Configuration -> Select "default" element/ Application -> then change working directory*

Comment: But i couldn't see "project compiler output" option in "Project Structure" . could you please suggest on this.

Comment: You can use menu RUN -> Edit Configuration -> Select "default" element/ Application -> then change working directory

Comment: I don't really get your point. Why do i need to change working directory? It's currently in hello world.

Comment: I think the config of this app does not match you PC. This issue often occurs when download source code from other. For Ex: I share a source code, that was reconfigured to run as my PC on "F:\projects\" but when you download, your computer does not have F driver, so you have to change the output folder. I means "You should change the output folder"

Comment: I agree.But here I haven't downloaded it from anywhere.I have just created a "Hello world". And i am failing to run it.

Comment: Please try this topic to build signed APK, may It will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio