# Can't find the generated APK file

Tags: android, android-studio

I followed the instructions here..

[How do I export a project in the Android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio)

I name my .jks file with Test1 but cant find any Test1.apk file in my project folder
neither do i find a BIN folder...

Answer (score 4):

Open the project in file explorer and go to : `\app\build\outputs`. You should see the `apk` folder there.

Comment: thankss i see it now and was able to install it on the device

Answer (score 1):

The .jks file is a keystore, the next step in the answer you link is the one which generates the actual .apk, there is a path to where it is going to be put right there in the top textbox. (`Destination APK path:`)

As you mention that you generated the .jks, you can just go Build -> Generate signed APK... now, fill in the passwords, chose your Test1.jks and try again. If this does not work, try unchecking the `ProGuard` tickbox.

Also, the default name for your .apk is not the keystore name, but your app name.