# How can I get Apk file...?

Tags: android, apk

I am new for Android that's why i'm asking this much of doubts. I Developed one project i want send Apk file to some one else.i want get my APK file from my project please help me.

Comment: Build -> Generate signed apk

Comment: For generating signed apk please refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19876060/2078074).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your project is file explorer then open app folder then open build folder then open output folder then open apk folder...here you will get your apks.
**File Explorer-->app-->build-->Output-->apk folder**

[image]

Comment: but i want to know in pc only

Comment: Mind that @Saurabh's answer is for unsigned APK.

Comment: not for mobile....or you can also do this with android studio..just right click on app folder and click on show in explorer

Comment: As Lawrance said...if you want signed apk then first of all you have to create signed apk through Build-->generate signed apk in android studio... @Lawrance

Comment: where is that App im not getting

Comment: App is the name of the folder in your project

Comment: @chandra..I have attached the image where blue heading showing the app folder

Comment: @saurabh it's working now.but its working in android studio only(in android studio right click on apps file Explorer then only it's working ordinary it's not working)why...???

Comment: @chandra..Both ways for getting an apk file either through android studio or simple window file explorer are the same...basically you are reaching to the same path......then what's the difference or I am not getting you properly

Answer (score 1):

**Build -> Build APK**.
If you want to create a signed APK you should follow other process but i think you will be ok with this. Then Android Studio generate link to your local folder in event log with apk.

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**For Eclipse.**

> You can take it from Your Project -> bin folder.

**From Android Studio.**

> You can take it from Your Project -> app -> build -> outputs -> apk -> app-debug.apk

`If you want to generate signed APK it will give you option where you want to generate your APK and set your path.`

Answer (score 0):

Using Android Studio
Build -> Generate APK 
then the output apk build location will appear.

Or

YourProjectName -> app -> build -> outputs -> apk