# I cant run apps on the emulator anymore

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pixel, nexus-5

I updated android studio recently and now I cannot run them in the emulator anymore.

When I press the green arrow for "run app" everything works like normal, the emulator is starting and it runs fine, I can use it as normal but my own app does not launch on it. The lightning bolt is grayed out and it says "Apply changes: no active 'app' launch"

If I press the green arrow which has always worked just fine before to run the new code on the emulator, it tells me AVD Pixel is already running, if that is not the case delete these files. There is no problem here, the emulator is indeed running and I can close it and reopen it just fine, my app just wont get installed on it.

I tried installing a new emulator and the new emulator worked just fine but still my app wont install on it. I have tried turning instant run off, I have tried new projects and old projects. I have not changed anything I have just pressed the "update" button when I had a popup for it in android studio about a week ago.

Comment: Maybe your app is broken? What says the Terminal, the Console and the Gradle build log?

Comment: Would a brand new app also be broken? I cant even run a new blank "hello world" project. The "run" window says: "03/13 13:27:13: Launching app" and pretty much nothing in the terminal. The emulator just starts and nothing else happens.

Comment: I was just asking, you never know ;) What about the gradle log? Does the Android Version of the Emulator supports the Android Version of the App. Do you tried to export the App to a APK and install it manually?

Comment: Well I installed a brand new version of google pixel emulator so I think so. The gradle says it needs api level 23 only and I think the pixel should be at api level 24. Plus I am just starting to learn java so its nothing more advanced than some textviews and some arraylists. I have not tried to do it manually, how do i do that?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16622843/how-do-i-export-a-project-in-the-android-studio) to create a APK file. Do you have your SourceCode available on Github or so? Then I will try it later.

Comment: Well the source code isnt really my own, I have just been following udacity's guides. The thing is, I havent changed a single character in the code, the code worked just fine last week. Then I was booting up android studio and it told me there was an update so I just clicked it and now I cannot run my code anymore.

Comment: Oh and also, well I pressed "build APK" and got a file that I drag and dropped into the emulator and now it has been stuck on a mode of "Installing apk" for the past 5 minutes with no signs of progress.

Comment: Mh, curios. Do you tried to launch it on an real Android Device?

Comment: Do you tried to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio?

Comment: I was about to try reinstalling android studio if this didnt work and I will probably do that if this problem comes back.