# Possible to send "release" build, over USB cable, from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, digital-signature

Using Android Studio 0.6.1 (actually on OSX), normally I have build variant set on "debug".

[image]

I have a phone plugged in "Connected as a media device".  I click the "Run" button up top.

[image]

Everything works fantastically well.

However. Say I change this to "release" ...

[image]

it seems impossible, to now send it over the USB to the phone?

I understand that to publish to the Play Store, I use "release" and use "build signed apk", using the password for the keystone. That works perfectly.

So can I just "leave it on" "release" mode while working with the tethered phones?

(With iOS development for example, the "debug" setting is just annoying and sucks, and you can just leave it on "release" all the time, basically. Indeed you can just delete the "debug" variant.)

---

Here's the error that appears if you try to send a "release" build over the USB cable to a tethered phone.

[image]

Comment: What error did you get when you tried it?

Comment: "SoBut can I just "leave it on" "release" mode while working with the tethered phones?" what's stopping you?

Comment: HI Chris, as it says, I can not do that. If you try that you get an error -- notice I pasted in an image showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The Android system requires that all installed applications be [digitally signed](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) with a certificate whose private key is held by the application's developer.

Have you set up a [key-store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore) for signing the release build?

for details using gradle see [how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328730/how-to-create-a-release-signed-apk-file-using-gradle)

With android studio 0.5.9 you can use `Module settings [F4]/app signing` to define the key store.

Comment: For sure, everything works absolutely perfectly, **when creating a release build** to save on my desktop and then send to the playstore (or whatever).  We have apps for clients actually on the play store, and it all works, hooray.  My problem is, it appears I can't use a tethered device, without changing to "debug".  Is there a way to use "release" with a tethered ADB device?  Cheers...

Comment: oh i see: if you run "gradle --gui" there is a gradle task "installDebug" but there is no gradle taks "installRelease". so your actual quiestion should be "how to creade android gradle task "installRelease"? manually you can execute on the commandline "adb install /path/to/file.apk". but maybe there is a better way to do it