# How can I get Cordova to automatically sign release APKs?

Tags: android, cordova

In [Cordova 5](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_overview_index.md.html#Overview), how can I incorporate [`zipaligning`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html) and [`signing`](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) of the APK using my [`keystore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore) into the build process?

Using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com), I can specify an `ant.properties` file that includes the lines below:

```
key.store=CylonApp.keystore
key.alias=CylonApp
```

such that running `ionic build android --release` automatically prepares an APK that can be submitted directly to [the Play Store](https://play.google.com/apps/publish).

Is there an equivalent in Cordova?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `release-signing.properties` in `platforms/android` and adding the following:

```
storeFile=<path to="" .keystore="" file="">
storeType=jks
keyAlias=<your key="" alias="">
// optional :
keyPassword=<your-key-password>
storePassword=<your-store-password>
```

Comment: Does it also perform zipaligning?