# How to reuse the existing keystore in different system for creating signed apk

Tags: android

I have a keystore which is created from one machine and i am in need to use the same keystore in different system. Is this possible..? If it is, please help me out that how to do this?

Note: This is not a gradle project. This is ant

Comment: just locate you keystore you want to use when you are exporting project...you  can check my [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30254012/2553431)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. You just need to give the password of the keystore while signing the apk.

Answer (score 0):

You need have password of keystore and password of alias (if you want to reuse that alias).
EDIT:
[image]

If you want to create new alias, You chose radio button on below: Create new alias.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using eclipse mars to signing the apk. It is asking alias name while going with existing keystore. But there is no option to give alias name, because it is in selection mode. (or) If it can done by command prompt, please provide the command to export the signed apk