# Livecode Development Test Error

Tags: livecode

Good Day,

I have Livecode 7.1 Community edition.  I made a small program, I want to test it in an emulator.  It is not working I get this error:

[image]

[image]

I am using windows 7 64.

I have sdk and avd running.  I am not sure what else I need to do.

Thank you for looking at this.

Comment: Have you installed API 8 (Android 2.2 or 2.2.3)? Did you select the Android folder in the LiveCode preferences folder?

Comment: Hi Mark, yep all is good at that point.  It seems when I try to send it over to the Virtual Android emulator it fails. Thank you for tryin though :)

Comment: Just want to add in case you missed adding the right `keystore` - just follow instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the guide for installation here: http://livecode.wikia.com/wiki/Android_set_up_enviroment ??