# Xamarin Build Android Sign APK in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a build step setup to sign my APK file using:

```
/t:SignAndroidPackage
```

[image]

I then push to Hockey App for beta releases. The problem I'm having is that when the user downloads the new APK and chooses to update on their phone, I receive the "App not Installed" error.

After researching I feel it's some how related to this:

['App not Installed' Error on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226132/app-not-installed-error-on-android)

However I'm not sure how exactly to change my build process so it's always signing with the same certificate (if that is my issue).

What do I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried substituting values as properties for the build step? E.g. here is how we are doing it on Jenkins (admittedly not VSTS but should show the point): jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ${KEYSTORE_FILE} -storepass $KEYSTORE_PW -keypass $APK_KEY_PW -signedjar "${APK_SIGNED}" "${APK_BUILT}" $APK_KEY_ALIAS

Comment: Isn't there dedicated build task for it `Signing and aligning APK file(s)` ? Also check here https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/build/apps/mobile/xamarin#define-your-xamarin-android-build

Answer (score 0):

Found [this in Xamarin Build Process documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/) that looks like it specifies the properties to be used for MSBuild, per my comment about substituting values.

Looks like this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>filename.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>keystore.filename.password</AndroidSigningStorePass>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>keystore.alias</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>keystore.alias password</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
</PropertyGroup>
```

You should be able to use MSBuild variables to get the pathing correct for the keystore file.

Comment: Hey thanks! But I guess my question is how do I generate the Android key in the first place? Is there a specific process to go through?

Comment: Looks like I can run with this! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore

Comment: It would be cool if you combine these ideas into a complete answer specific to VSTS.

Comment: Mark - that's my goal, haven't gotten it fully figured out yet