# Error:(29,0), When importing github project to Android Studio

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I am trying to import the [git](https://github.com/vishesh/sealnote.git) project.

Sadly everytime I clone the project I get the following error:

```
Error:(29, 0) Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='D:\Path\Sealnote'
```

On clicking the hyperlink, it takes me to the build.gradle file, specifically to:

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file(System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEYSTORE"))
            storePassword System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
            keyAlias System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEY_ALIAS")
            keyPassword System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEY_PASSWORD")
        }
    }
```

I am guessing since this is a signed release I will need a key to use the project, but what is the point of it being opensource if we cant use it?

Comment: You need a key when creating a signed apk, that has nothing to do with the import process.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove these lines since they are used to generate signed APK without prompting for keystore's username and password

```
    storeFile file(System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEYSTORE"))
    storePassword System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD")
    keyAlias System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEY_ALIAS")
    keyPassword System.getenv("SEALNOTE_KEY_PASSWORD")
```

Otherwise, you will need to set Environment Variables for these keys.

Answer (score 0):

`System.getenv` is meant to retrieve System Environment variables. In your case since you are cloning someone else's repository you do not have those system variables and the required values in them.

The developer who owns the repository was fetching the environment variables on the operating system.

You can do one of the following:

1. Delete that configuration from the release block and manually select your keystore when generating release apks.
2. Replace the values for the four config fields with your own keystore details.
3. Create those environment variables and specify values for your keystore.

---

- Here is how you create environment variables - [Link](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7)
- Here is how you create a keystore - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore)

Comment: After the resolution of these errors, I am facing another issue, please see  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952427/sqlcipher-causing-app-to-crash-on-launch) here.