# com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

Im implementing an android app that enables users to stream to a youtube channel straight from the app. I have created an API key and a OAuth 2.0 client ID [image]

But I get a the following exeption: `com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE` either when I try to ceate an event or when i try to fetch the one a created manually on the youtube channel.

I use the following code for create a youtube object

```
String accountName = mContext.getString(R.string.google_account_name);
        String apiKey = mContext.getString(R.string.google_api_key);
        String clientID = mContext.getString(R.string.google_api_client_id);
        String clientName = mContext.getString(R.string.google_api_client_name);

        GoogleAccountCredential credential =
                GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mContext,
                        Arrays.asList(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE));
        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);

//        String SCOPE = "audience:server:client_id:" + clientID + ":api_scope:" + YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE;
//        GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(mContext, SCOPE);
//        credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);


        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(clientName)
                .setYouTubeRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(apiKey))
                /*.setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new YouTubeRequestInitializer(apiKey))*/
                .build();
```

Then to create an event:

```java
LiveBroadcastSnippet broadcastSnippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet();
broadcastSnippet.setTitle(name);
broadcastSnippet.setScheduledStartTime(new DateTime(futureDate));

LiveBroadcastContentDetails contentDetails = new LiveBroadcastContentDetails();
MonitorStreamInfo monitorStream = new MonitorStreamInfo();
monitorStream.setEnableMonitorStream(false);
contentDetails.setMonitorStream(monitorStream);

// Create LiveBroadcastStatus with privacy status.
LiveBroadcastStatus status = new LiveBroadcastStatus();
status.setPrivacyStatus("unlisted");

LiveBroadcast broadcast = new LiveBroadcast();
broadcast.setKind("youtube#liveBroadcast");
broadcast.setSnippet(broadcastSnippet);
broadcast.setStatus(status);
broadcast.setContentDetails(contentDetails);

// Create the insert request
YouTube.LiveBroadcasts.Insert liveBroadcastInsert = youtube
        .liveBroadcasts().insert("snippet,status,contentDetails",
                            broadcast);
    
// Request is executed and inserted broadcast is returned
LiveBroadcast returnedBroadcast = liveBroadcastInsert.execute(); //<= This line generates the exception
```

I obviously did something wrong, but I can't figure out what. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that, when you debug, you're using a keystore created in ~/.android/debug.keystore, and not whatever signing key you think you're using.

When you generate a key, such as to release a signed APK, you think that this SHA1 is the one required by the Google API interface. It isn't.

If you replace the one in the ~/.android folder with your signing key, it's corrupt because it's missing the androiddebugkey. FYI, the default password for the auto-generated key is "android".

For directions as to where your keystore is located, see https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html under "Expiry of the debug certificate".

What you have to do:

1) Delete your debug.keystore and restart your IDE. This should generate a new debug.keystore with key alias "androiddebugkey".

2) If your IDE does not generate the new keystore, re-run your android application. It should generate it this time in ~/.android/

3) Navigate to /path/to/jre/bin and add this path to your system environment variables. This will allow you to access `keytool`.

4) Navigate to the directory of your debug keystore and run this command: `keytool -list -keystore debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey`

5) Your console will prompt you to enter the keystore password (it is "android").

6) Get the SHA1 key from the keystore and put THAT KEY into your API interface, and you'll find it works.

Comment: Restarting the IDE did not regenerate the file. Is there something more I need to do?

Comment: Same thing happened for me too.

Comment: Try the suggestions in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore

Answer (score 6):

In my case the UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE error was caused by misspell in package name in AndroidManifest. Simple but lost many hours struggling with keys and SHAs.

Comment: Or when you switch from debug key to a final one and forget to update your SHA. Gosh! Wasted hours of my life.

Answer (score 2):

Using the answers before this, I used it as a reference to understand and fix mine and made a much easier step-by step procedure of how I fixed mine.

In Windows command prompt.

Navigate to you java bin directory.

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin>

and type the ff. command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

then run the ff. code

```
keytool -list -keystore  "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey
```

when ask for password, type "android" (without double quotes)

the resulting SHA1 key from the above code. Copy it, and paste it on your google cloud console [here](http://console.cloud.google.com)

[image]

On the google cloud console webpage do this

on the tab on the left, find and click "APIs & Services"

then on the new page, on the left tab again, find and click "Credentials"

now copy paste the key you copied from windows command prompt on the textbox below the "Signing-certificate fingerprint"

make sure that the application id on your app and google cloud console matches each other.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've this problem, and after a lot of search, in `build.gadle` my `applicationId` was diferent from the package name that i've putted on Google Console

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "br.com.glicado.glicado" <-- WAS WRONG, IN MY CASE THE RIGHT IS "br.com.glicado"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```