# Unable to generate keystore and release cocos2dx project

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I tried to generate the keystore however, Seems like it's not working. I'm not used to create the apk and release via terminal. So if I may be doing something wrong, it would be great if you can tell me some hints or samples.

My location of the project

```
/Users/myself/Desktop/CocoFolder/MyGame
```

Tried the following code. But not sure what to enter.

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore /Users/myself/Desktop/CocoFolder/MyGame
 -alias MyGame -validity 10000
```

Planning to use this to create a release apk.

```
cocos run -s/Users/myself/Desktop/CocoFolder/MyGame -p android –android-studio -m release
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions :

1. How I generate keystore that required to sign your apk

   [How can I create a keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore)
2. Done you've now your keystore with specified alias name, Now you want to generate signed apk from your keystore.

   Put this into`~/.gradle/gradle.properties`

   ```
   RELEASE_STORE_FILE={path to your keystore}
   RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
   RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=*****
   RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
   ```

   After that, Build --> Select Build Variant --> Set release for your game and build.

Comment: Thank you, one last thing. I get the following error when I uploaded the apk to the store. What does this mean? I've set the  validity to 10000.    "You uploaded an APK signed with a certificate that expires too soon. You need to sign your APK with a certificate that expires farther into the future"

Comment: Set expiration to be greater than 50 years.  `-validity 20000`