# Meteor.loginWithGoogle error 10 on android

Tags: android, meteor, meteor-accounts

I used the function Meteor.loginWithGoogle as below to login with google.
It's working on browser but It's fail (the console log is **error 10**) when I build to apk (by cordova).

```
handleLoginError(err, service) {
   console.error(err);
}

Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    this.handleLoginError(err, 'google');
  } else {
    this.handleLoginSuccess();
  }
});
```

Comment: Some additional information would be helpful, stack traces, the actual network calls and results, things like that.

Comment: Quey and @Peteor Olson have you checked the [docs on properly releasing to the playstore](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#submitting-android) (especially the part "Android Play Store")

Answer (score 4):

Just found the solution on https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/google-login-error-10/93230/4

In your case, Cordova is not signing your APK correctly. This is why the error only occurs in the apk. You can solve this by creating a valid keystore, which Cordova can use to sign the apk.

---

**Option 1**

You can create the keystore using e.g. this command: `keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
Make sure to edit it to your needs. If you want to know more about this command, you can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330139/8160563).

Next, you neew to get the SHA1 from the key you just generated using this command: `keytool -exportcert -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore`

You can use this SHA1 to get your token, IDs and keys from https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin

Use the command `meteor build android --release` to build your app and to generate an apk file.

Finally you can use the command `jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk alias_name` to jar sign the generated apk file with the keystore.

---

**Option 2**

Alternatively you can create a signing properties file `platforms/android/debug-signing.properties` containing your keystore file, password as shown below. Example:

```
keyAlias=yourkeyAlias
keyPassword=yourkeyPassword
storeFile=theFileContainingTheKeystore
storePassword=yourStorePassword
```

---

You can get more information about this in the publishing documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

Comment: Note that `cordova build android --release` needs to be `meteor build` as cordova is embedded in the Meteor environment. Edit see the [docs](https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#building-for-production)

Comment: Thank you very much for that information! I just edited the answer.

Comment: I finally got it working. In the end, there were two details that I needed: 1) I had to create a Google Firebase project, add the Google sign-in method there, and add the app's SHA1 certificate in the project settings. It automatically created new credentials in the Google API console where I got the client ID from before. 2) Google Play automatically handled the app signing for me, so I had to just copy the SHA certificate from the Google Play console.

Comment: It seems the link in the answer https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?platform=android&cntapi=signin is now redirecting to Google Firebase, so I was confused and didn't know that I had to create a Firebase project.