# Meteor Android Oauth2 google account error 10

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, meteor-accounts

I am using MeteorJS and cordova build for Android, I am using Meteor.loginwithgoogle() method which works fine with web browser, but when debugging the app on android device it returns with error 10 and refuses to authenticate, I am not using any related plugins, just the accounts-google package, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor.loginWithGoogle error 10 on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854992/meteor-loginwithgoogle-error-10-on-android)