# I'm not a programmer. Need help to upload Android app to Google play store

Tags: android, google-play-services

I got APK file from my developer saying that, that is all I need. I've been stuck in the part of signing the app. I have read through the articles and from what I understand I need a .ks file or private key to finish the procedure. 
I'm not sure if I understand the app signing process or should I download Android studio to sign the app manually.

If the developer has signed the app, what is my procedure henceforth? Would I need a keystore file?

Comment: The developer must sign the app while compiling.

Comment: [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html)

Comment: So I'll need a keystore file from developer?

Comment: have the developer sign the apk (which would make it ready for upload) and ask him for the keystore and the keystore password in case you might want to release an update for the app that is done by another developer later on.

Comment: No. you can create a keystore file yourself and remeber to keep it safe or else you won't be able to sign next versions.
us this link to create keystore file.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming apk has been signed by the developer.

**Step one**:

go to the play console: 
https://developer.android.com/index.html login to the account you would like to use to publish your app.

**Step two**:

Once logged in hit the '**create application**' button set the default languade & title.

**Step three**:

complete the form, this is your store listing, which includes images, app description, app name etc.

**Step four**:

go to the app releases tab, then to 'production', accept T&C, you will then see a button that says 'upload apk' click that button then use the apk file that has been provided by the developer, complete the rest of the form which will complete uploading your app.