# Google Developer console ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have create apk zip aligned with kivy/buildozer i have upload a apk in google developer console but when the download have finish i have this  ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_MANIFEST: Missing META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  who help me?? thanks in advance

Comment: Did you sign the APK?

Comment: NO,can u help me sign the apk?? i use xubuntu in the virtual machine kivy/buildozer Thanks

Comment: @MaxAndMax try to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Creating-a-Release-APK).

Comment: How to create an Android keystore ? im a beginner

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov Gerasimov 
 
How to create an Android keystore ? im a beginner THANKS in advance please tell me the commands i use xubuntu

Comment: @MaxAndMax I didn't create it myself, but it's plenty instructions all over internet. For example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15330139/1113207

Comment: i need a noob help here but thanks Mikhailil

Comment: @inclement 
 
i need a noob help here for create a keystore thanks in advance