# how to change Firebase project in Android Studio module

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-assistant

My android project initially was connect to a Firebase project. I need to connect the app to a different project.

I use the "Firebase Assistant" and it kept on complaining:

```
The app is already connected to a project "xxx". 
Click "Sync" to update the configuration info
Additional Info: 
Package Name: "xxxxx" 
SHA1: "xxxxx"
```

If I create a brand new AS project just to test it out, the new AS project does give me choices to pick the old or the new one.

I have tried many ways, manually download the google-service.json file, or tried to clean as much as I can from build, etc.  But somehow my Android studio project still not allow me to choose the new Firebase Project I setup in console.

Please share any tips to achieve my goal, and thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: you have to change the project settings for your new firebase project like package name, SHA1. then you have to download new google-services.json and place it in your app folder and rest i think you know.

Comment: The app is already in production/PlayStore.  changing package probably is not an option for me.  Can I change SHA1 and the app still appears the same app in PlayStore?  Where to change the SHA1?

Comment: for this you need to [create different keystore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997748/how-can-i-create-a-keystore) for development process, from generated keystore you will get different SHA1, which can be used in firebase.

Comment: SHA1 is linked to keystore used for signing the app. And Google play console will not allow you to upload app signed with different key

Comment: I strongly agree with AbdulAli, but if @Sean need to make an development project on firebase then you can use by creating different SHA1.

Comment: As long as I can get the production build working, I care less on development/debug build at this moment :-(

Comment: @Sean Did you ever get this working? I have the same problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue and I managed to solve it by deleting the google-services.json file and then initiating the connect to firebase method again.