# APK Signature conflicting by formatting PC

Tags: android

**What's The matter**

I built a **debug APK** and share it to client by downloadable link. Few days back, I formatted my PC. Now again I gave an update to client for existing APK. When client tries to update (without uninstalling older one), app shows *Android App Not Install*.

---

I would like to know, do the Signature of APK before and after **formatting PC** will be different?

If 'YES',

- What are the possible solutions for updating newer APK on
  older(installed) one?

If 'NO',

- Why I am getting, *Android App Not Install. An existing package by the
  same name with a conflicting signature is already installed*

Comment: There is a strong chance that the signature is indeed different after formatting the PC. For a debug APK, uninstalling the older one before installing the new one is the only solution i know if this is the case. To avoid that, sign properly your APK

Comment: Probably. Have you tried installing a release version over the debug one? Usually when I do that over with adb install -r <apkname> it does the job.

Comment: @DavisJP let me try it out. But still, You mean to say, I need to bring client's personal device. right?

Comment: If you send him the apk, I think he should be able to open and install it from any file manager from inside his device.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to know, do the Signature of APK before and after
>   formatting PC will be different?

**Yes,** if you are using default debug keystore. This is normally the case if you are building your apk through Android Studio. This keystore will be deleted after you have formatted the PC. A new keystore will be created after you install the Android-Studio

**No,** if you maintain your keystore seprately and use it consistantly to sign your app before release

**Solutions**

- If you have used debug keystore then only solution is to uninstall your previous app and install a new one
- If you have just missed the signing configuration, then simply create a new APK signed with correct keystore.
- Checkout my [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51073164/how-to-make-multiple-workstations-build-app-compatible-on-one-android-device/51073179#51073179) if you want to ensure that in future, all your dev workstation should produce debug apps signed with same keystore, even if you format your PC.

Comment: In my case, I should not share release APK to client. So, hopefully I should convince client to uninstall older one. LOL

Comment: @Dhruv yeah! You are lucky in that case :-D