# keystore and private key migration

Tags: android

I have and issue when I try to generate signed-apk. Well, I have a laptop what was used to development my android app using android studio by other hand I have a desktop with clean android installation.

I copied /home/.android folder from m laptop to my desktop but when I try to compile a signed-apk I get follow error message: cannot recover key. Either if I compile it on my laptop I am able to get signed apk.

Do I am missing something?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added these in your build.gradle:

```
signingConfigs{
        config {
            keyAlias '****'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('****.keystore')
            storePassword '****'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where I can found keystore? Regards

Comment: Here is complete method(Eclipse and android studio). https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254012/11696949

Answer (score 0):

On your laptop you might be using existing keystore path that is the .jks file , use the same file to generate signed apk on your desktop. See if this works.

Comment: I did it before ask here without luck