# Troupbles with creating apk with React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, apk

I'm new too React Native and just created an app with this command
    react-native init rnapp
It's ouputed many warnings:

```
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\jest-haste-map\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","a
rch":"x64"})
npm WARN react-native@0.61.5 requires a peer of react@16.9.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: abbrev@1.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\abbrev' -> 'D:\rn
app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.abbrev.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ansi-regex@2.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ansi-regex' -> 'D
:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ansi-regex.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: aproba@1.2.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aproba' -> 'D:\rn
app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.aproba.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: balanced-match@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\balanced-match' -
> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.balanced-match.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: chownr@1.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chownr):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\chownr' -> 'D:\rn
app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.chownr.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: code-point-at@1.1.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\code-point-at' ->
 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.code-point-at.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: concat-map@0.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\concat-map' -> 'D
:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.concat-map.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: console-control-strings@1.1.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-strings):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\console-control-s
trings' -> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.console-control-strings.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: core-util-is@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\core-util-is' ->
'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.core-util-is.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: deep-extend@0.6.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\deep-extend):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\deep-extend' -> '
D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.deep-extend.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: delegates@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\delegates' -> 'D:
\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.delegates.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: detect-libc@1.0.3 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\detect-libc):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\detect-libc' -> '
D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.detect-libc.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fs.realpath@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\fs.realpath' -> '
D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.fs.realpath.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: has-unicode@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\has-unicode' -> '
D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.has-unicode.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: inherits@2.0.4 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\inherits' -> 'D:\
rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.inherits.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ini@1.3.5 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ini' -> 'D:\rnapp
\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ini.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: isarray@1.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isarray):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\isarray' -> 'D:\r
napp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.isarray.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@0.0.8 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\minimist' -> 'D:\
rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ms@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ms):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\ms' -> 'D:\rnapp\
node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.ms.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: npm-normalize-package-bin@1.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npm-normalize-package-bin):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\npm-normalize-pac
kage-bin' -> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.npm-normalize-package-bin.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: number-is-nan@1.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\number-is-nan' ->
 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.number-is-nan.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: object-assign@4.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\object-assign' ->
 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.object-assign.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-homedir@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-homedir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-homedir' -> 'D
:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.os-homedir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: os-tmpdir@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-tmpdir):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\os-tmpdir' -> 'D:
\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.os-tmpdir.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: path-is-absolute@1.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\path-is-absolute'
 -> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.path-is-absolute.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: process-nextick-args@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-args):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\process-nextick-a
rgs' -> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.process-nextick-args.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: minimist@1.2.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\minimist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\m
inimist' -> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\rc\node_modules\.minimist.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safe-buffer@5.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safe-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safe-buffer' -> '
D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.safe-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: safer-buffer@2.1.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safer-buffer):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\safer-buffer' ->
'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.safer-buffer.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: sax@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sax):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\sax' -> 'D:\rnapp
\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.sax.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: semver@5.7.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\semver' -> 'D:\rn
app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.semver.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: set-blocking@2.0.0 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\set-blocking' ->
'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.set-blocking.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: signal-exit@3.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\signal-exit' -> '
D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.signal-exit.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: strip-json-comments@2.0.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-json-comments):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\strip-json-commen
ts' -> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.strip-json-comments.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: util-deprecate@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\util-deprecate' -
> 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.util-deprecate.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: wrappy@1.0.2 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\wrappy' -> 'D:\rn
app\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.wrappy.DELETE'
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: yallist@3.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\rnapp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\yallist' -> 'D:\r
napp\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\.yallist.DELETE'
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0 requires a peer of eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies your
self.
npm WARN eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4 requires a peer of eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies you
rself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0 requires a peer of eslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.
6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","a
rch":"x64"})
```

Then I went to android folder and ran this command:

```
gradlew assemblerelease
```

But then I get this:

> *> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets warning: the transform cache was reset. Loading dependency graph, done. info Writing bundle output to:,
>   D:\rnapp\android\app\build\generated\assets\react\release\index.android.bundle
>   info Writing sourcemap output to:,
>   D:\rnapp\android\app\build\generated\sourcemaps\react\release\index.android.bundle.map
>   info Done writing sourcemap output info Done writing bundle output
>   info Copying 2 asset files info Done copying assets
>   Task :app:mergeReleaseResources FAILED
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
>   8 exceptions were raised by workers:
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
>     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
>     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.2-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed*

Anyone knows how to fix that and build apk file for Android on that empty application?

Comment: did you read from the official website of react-native that how we can create apk file?

Comment: open your project's android folder with android studio and generate release apk from there.

Comment: Yes I've read official manual and created keystore file.

Comment: All submenus at Android Studio in Build and Run menus are disabled

Answer (score 1):

Here's a link to the official react-native website where it shows how to build signed android apk.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android#__docusaurus

First, you need to create a keystore, here's how to create a keystore (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30254012/4829343) and then follow the instructions on the react-native website.

Comment: I've read that and created keystore file. And still I got the same error

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can clean your Gradle file, then use this command `./gradlew assembleRelease`.